# Is the use of "acquainted with" correct here?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

Accidentally, I was acquainted with a NGO called Liren University, which was dedicated to providing a universal education for youths on liberal arts.

I do not know how to describe this sort of knowing. I only know a little about this NGO. In this case, can I say "acquainted with"? or better "acquaint myself with"?

Answer (score 1):

> I only know a little about this NGO.

"Acquainted with" would suggest more knowledge (though the idiom is rather vague).

> Accidentally, I became aware of an NGO called…

only explicitly states a very minimal amount of knowledge, which hence conveys modesty and avoids the risk of falsely suggesting a much wider knowledge than you have.

The fact that you give more information about the NGO balances this, since you obviously have a enough of a knowledge of it to enable you to do so, so the risk of going too far in that direction is minimised too.

"I made myself aware…" is good too, but your use of "accidentally" suggests you became aware of them by chance, and "I made myself" suggests greater volition and intent.

Incidentally, note that it's "an NGO", not "a NGO", because it's "an En-Gee-Oh" and *a/an* follows pronunciation.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it would be better to say "I acquainted (the rest of your sentence is in the past participle), myself with the NGO called..."

Since the subject you're talking about is more so a thing rather than a person, it would be better to say 'yourself' in the sentence.

I'm hoping you mean 'NGO' as in "Non-Governmental Organization" in this sentence.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your answer completely solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, it solved your problem, except for the fact that you need to drop the "a" before "universal education", and change the "on" before "liberal arts" to "in". Also think about removing "for youths", as it is obvious that youths are who gets educated at a university. (unless it caters to some special class of youths, such as very young ("precocious","advanced") or very poor ("disadvantaged") youths. Another hint: in AmE we usually use "youth" as the plural of "youth", or else call them "young people".